# Can ping but can't do anything else

Tags: dns, ping

Ok, I seem to have an internet connection because I'm able to ping external ip addresses.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=356 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=266 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=356 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=339 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=267 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 5 received, 16% packet loss, time 5001ms
```

But for some reason I am not able to do anything else.

```
$ drill @8.8.8.8 google.com
Error: error sending query: Could not send or receive, because of 
network error
```

I have tried on several devices on the network and have tried re-booting the router.

I originally thought the problem might have been due to the dns server on the network but after disabling that and using Google's service I am getting the same problem.

This is a problem with a home network.  Nothing fancy.  ISP supplied router and a small home server doing DNS, DHCP and some file sharing stuff.

I have no internet connection so can't download traceroute but here is a tracepath

```
$ tracepath 8.8.8.8 -b
1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1432
1:  _gateway (192.168.1.1)                                0.684ms  
1:  _gateway (192.168.1.1)                                0.631ms  
2:  no reply
3:  no reply
^C
```

I hope I am asking this in the right place.   Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:** 
Thanks for your help so far.   I'll add some more info that might help.

I am having this problem on all the devices on the network. This includes 2 Arch Linux machines, one Ubuntu and two android divides.

It has only recently stopped working.  I haven't done any updates that would have caused the issue.

I have spoken to my ISP and they say they can't see any faults on the line.

Firewall is built into the router.   Very basic and with all defaults except I have a random port open for ssh access - only via public key.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall(s)?

Comment: You may not have all the software you need installed. Or you may have a router configuration error. To eliminate DNS problems ping a known web site, such as `google.com` on the machine you used for this question, then try using the IP address on the faulty system. To eliminate software configuration errors, try testing with a Live Boot disc. Then update your question with the information from your tests, and tell us your OS.

Comment: do you have an antivirus package installed? More than once, I've had to yank it and re-install for others, to get internet access.

Comment: Seems like IP addresses get through but not DNS. You mentioned a local DNS server in your network and it might be the cause of the problem. You really don't need one for a small home network.

Comment: @harrymc , thanks.   I thought that.   Disabling it and using ISP's or Google's doesn't fix it.   I have 2 reasons for having a Dns server.   One: I have a media server that I like to be able to easily access on the network and I develop websites for a living and having a dns server makes it super easy to point all *.dev domains to my development machine which makes testing on portable devices really easy

Comment: I would disable the dns server, disable all firewalls including router, turn off all equipment except one PC, and get down to the really basic setup until something finally works, then build back up until the bad element is found.

Comment: Looks very much like your router is stuffed. Reset it to defaults, reload firmware and reconfigure it.